# Exchange - Unable to initialise TCP Network connection

Tags: ssl, exchange

Today my Exchange server stopped receiving IMAP requests - webmail works fine and mail flow is fine, however it will not authenticate an IMAP request. My event logs show the following:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to initialise TCP Network 
connection ---> System.InvalidOperationException: SSL negotiation did 
not complete successfully: InvalidToken at Microsoft.Exchange.Monitoring.
ActiveMonitoring.Common.TcpConnection.NegotiateSSL() at Microsoft.Exchang
e.Monitoring.ActiveMonitoring.PopImap.Probes.PopImapProbeUtil.CreateImapS
SLStateObject(IPEndPoint targetAddress, ProbeResult result) --- End of 
inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Exchange.Monitoring.ActiveMo
nitoring.PopImap.Probes.ImapSelfTestProbe.HandleSocketError(Exception e) 
at Microsoft.Exchange.Monitoring.ActiveMonitoring.PopImap.Probes.PopImapP
robeBase.HandleConnectionExceptions(PopImapProbeStateObject 
probeTrackingObject) at Microsoft.Exchange.Monitoring.ActiveMonitoring.Po
pImap.Probes.ImapSelfTestProbe.DoWork(CancellationToken 
cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.Office.Datacenter.WorkerTaskFramework.WorkItem.Execute(
CancellationToken joinedToken) at 
Microsoft.Office.Datacenter.WorkerTaskFramework.WorkItem.<>
c__DisplayClass2.<StartExecuting>b__0() at 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I am not aware of any changes and have been searching extensively however can't find a solution to this. Desparately trying to get it back up.

Comment: Does only IMAP over SSL fail or also without SSL? Is your SSL Server certificate still valid?

Comment: I don't know as we only accept STARTTLS.

Comment: Okay I tried turning off TLS and this is still a problem.